# Selection of row by clicking link in RixhTextbox C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to select a cell in datagridview with multiple tabs by clicking a link in a rich text box. The link is a reference to a cell in that row sow it will search for that reference in a multidimdictlist with the same size as the number of tabs available, and will retrieve the index of the reference, which will be the same index of the row in the datagridview. The problem I encountered is that when I click a link that will take me to any other of the tabs but tab number 1 (with index i!= 0), it will not select the desired cell but two cells below.

This is the code I have:

```
  private void txtbox_LinkClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridFocus(e.LinkText);
    }
    public void DataGridFocus(string location)
    {

        location = location.Replace("_", " ");
        location = location.Replace(@"\", "");
        bool foundindex = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < Mod_config_data.Count; i++)
        {
            int index = Mod_config_data[i].IndexOf(location);
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                dataGridView0.ClearSelection();
                tabControl2.SelectedIndex = i;

                dataGridView0.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = index;
                dataGridView0.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = 0;
                dataGridView0.Rows[index].Selected = true;

                dataGridView0.CurrentCell = dataGridView0.Rows[index].Cells[0];
                foundindex = true;

            }
        }
```

Comment: ??                 ![enter image description here] ??

Comment: More questions: - `datagridview with multiple tabs` What does that mean?   - `tab number 1 (with index i!= 0)`Is that right? What is the index that's not working?   - `dataGridView0.Rows[index].Selected = true;` That selects a whole row, not cells. Which do you want?

Comment: its a datagridview nested inside a tabcontrol. so when i click a reference that should link to a cell/row in tab 1 lets say cell (x,y), it will select the desired cell in tab 1, but if the reference is in tab 2 the selection of cell/row will be done on tab 1 not tab 2.

Comment: sorry about ![enter image description here] im not sure where that came from

Comment: I still don't understand your layout. So you have **ONE** DataGridView? If it is **inside a Tab Control** it will have to be on **ONE** TabPage, right? So what does it mean that you want Cells selected in "tab 2" ? Are "tab 2" etc TabPages? Make sure you always call controls by their correct names. We can't help you unless you make all relevant details clear..